# Optimizing removal of duplicate rows from recursive CTE query

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a recursive SQL query to fetch multiple projects together with their lineage from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Project
(
Name VARCHAR(10),
ParentName VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Project(Name, ParentName) VALUES ('P', NULL);
INSERT INTO #Project(Name, ParentName) VALUES ('C1', 'P');
INSERT INTO #Project(Name, ParentName) VALUES ('C2', 'P');
SELECT Name, ParentName FROM #Project
```

(this is just a toy example, so please ignore table design issues and the lack of indexing)

So, given multiple project names, I need to fetch a table that contains the projects as well as all their ancestors, because the result table will have to support lineage queries for a given Project name

In order to do this, I came up with the following recursive CTE query:

```
WITH Lineage (Name, ParentName)
AS
(
SELECT        Name, ParentName
FROM            #Project WHERE Name = 'C1' OR Name = 'C2'
UNION ALL
SELECT        #Project.Name, #Project.ParentName
FROM            #Project INNER JOIN Lineage ON #Project.Name = Lineage.ParentName
)
SELECT Name, ParentName FROM Lineage
```

And, here is the result of the query:

```
Name | ParentName
C1   | P
C2   | P
P    | NULL
P    | NULL
```

As expected, this returns projects C1 and C2, as well as their parents, which will be duplicated for each child, unfortunately.

In order to get rid of the duplicated parents, I added `DISTINCT` to the final `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ParentName FROM Lineage
```

Which returns:

```
Name | ParentName
P    | NULL
C1   | P
C2   | P
```

Even though this produces the desired result, I am concerned about the performance of this query. The Lineage CTE will surely contain a lot of extra rows if I let it return these duplicates, which I remove at a later step in the query.

Is there any way to rewrite the CTE such that it removes these duplicates directly?

**UPDATE**: Just in case my example wasn't clear enough, I need to somehow specify the project names for which to fetch the lineages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? Kind of a hack - but row_number should be quicker than distinct.

```
;WITH Lineage AS
(
SELECT
    Name
   ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentName ORDER BY ParentName) > 1 
         THEN NULL 
         ELSE ParentName END AS ParentNameToJoin
   ,ParentName AS ParentNameToDisplay 
FROM
    #Project
WHERE
    Name in ('C1','C2')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    p.Name
   ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ParentName ORDER BY p.ParentName) > 1 
         THEN NULL 
         ELSE ParentName END AS ParentNameToJoin
   ,p.ParentName 
FROM
    #Project as p
INNER JOIN
    Lineage ON p.Name = Lineage.ParentNameToJoin
)
SELECT
    Name
   ,ParentNameToDisplay
FROM
    lineage
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a recursive CTE, you could consider using the [built-in `hierarchyid` SQL Server type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) to store the hierarchy.

I've put together a short [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) to illustrate how this works.

I'm doing this in `tempdb`:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Projects', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Projects;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Projects
(
    ProjectID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Projects
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ProjectName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , Hierarchy hierarchyid NOT NULL
);
```

Here I'm inserting some sample data.  Note `Top Project 2` is not referenced by any other project.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Projects (ProjectName, Hierarchy)
VALUES ('Top Project', '/1/')
    , ('Top Project 2', '/2/')
    , ('Child Project 1', '/1/3/')
    , ('Child Project 2', '/1/3/4/');

SELECT p.ProjectID
    , p.ProjectName
    , Hierarchy = p.Hierarchy.ToString()
FROM dbo.Projects p
```

Results:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ProjectID ║   ProjectName   ║ Hierarchy ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════╣
║         1 ║ Top Project     ║ /1/       ║
║         2 ║ Top Project 2   ║ /2/       ║
║         3 ║ Child Project 1 ║ /1/3/     ║
║         4 ║ Child Project 2 ║ /1/3/4/   ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

This query gets all the ancestor projects of `Child Project 2`:

```
SELECT p.ProjectID
    , p.ProjectName
    , Hierarchy = p.Hierarchy.ToString()
    , Parents = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + p1.ProjectName
    FROM dbo.Projects p1
    WHERE p.Hierarchy.IsDescendantOf(p1.Hierarchy) = 1
        AND p.Hierarchy <> p1.Hierarchy
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM dbo.Projects p
WHERE p.ProjectName = 'Child Project 2';
```

The results:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ ProjectID ║   ProjectName   ║ Hierarchy ║           Parents            ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║         4 ║ Child Project 2 ║ /1/3/4/   ║ Top Project, Child Project 1 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```